# Macros On Toolbar - Office 2000

Tags: database, ms-access, macros, ms-office

Someone at my office has an Access database which includes macros in the toolbar. To access it currently they have to log out of the domain and into a local user account. They would like others in the office to be able to access the database, which they can, but they cannot use the macros on the toolbars.

The Office version that is currently installed is Office 2000.

Is there any way to copy the macros out so that domain users can use them with the database?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to enable Macros to run they are probably disabled to protect against viruses.  To do this I think it is under the Tools Menu then Macros then Security.

You may require admin rights to do this.  If you set the security level to Medium the system will ask each time you open the database if it is safe to run Macros.

If you set it to Low it will run any Macros which may be dangerous depending on what is opened.

If you set it to High only signed or trusted Macros will be allowed to run.

Comment: This only works if there is no group policy in place that prohibits the execution of macros for domain users.

Comment: There's nothing dangerous about setting Macro Security to low. This is one of those cases where MS has crippled Access for no good safety reason.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, this can’t be macro security settings in access, as access 2000 did not have this feature.

As mentioned, this might be a group policy. Also, you state macros, but are you talking about VBA code or ms-access macros? While most of office we refer to code as macros, ms-access is different. For example word macros are VBA code. However, ms-access is different in this regards and ms-access has both macros and VBA code. So, they are not the same.

You can certainly look at and attempt to run and copy the macros by viewing the macros tab. You might have to hold down the shift key during startup – this will prevent any settings that hides the ms-access interface and allow you to look at, view, and copy those macros. So, is there code, or macros in the application?

You can copy those macros, but if group policy prevents this, copying the ability to copy the macros will not help here.

Comment: Good to see you here, Albert!